# how to create double select query

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"]; 
$lecturername = "SELECT lecturername FROM lecturer WHERE username='$username'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM publication WHERE lecturername='$lecturername'";
$records = mysql_query($sql);   
?>
```

Comment: Try using joins

Comment: `mysql.*` extensions are deprecated since I was young... use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Look at what your code is doing. `SELECT * FROM publication WHERE lecturername='SELECT lecturername FROM lecturer WHERE username='$username''` this would never work. You'd need to `execute`, `fectch`, `store`, and re-query. Using a `join` and 1 query will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) like this (just an example):

```
SELECT * FROM lecturer t1 JOIN publication t2 ON (t1.lecturername = t2.lecturername) WHERE username='$username'
```

This will return data of the combined tables lecturer and publication, using username to filter the results from lecturer table, and therefore publications.